# Send a failed response to C# from SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following in T-SQL 2014:

```
BEGIN

declare @JCID int;

set @JCID = (
select JobDetailsID
from JobCardDetails
where AMCEquipID = 5);

IF (@JCID > 0)

RETURN

END;

BEGIN

//next trans

END;
```

Obviously if @JCID = 0 I want it to continue with the stored procedure (whatever follows after the first "END;". Otherwise stop the stored procedure at "RETURN"  so that the rest after the first "END;" does not execute.

Then in C# (Windows forms) I use this to see if the query was successful:

```
                SQLConnect.Open();
                int q = SQLAddEquipQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (q == 0)
                {
                    //Not updated.
                    MessageBox.Show("has NOT been added successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Updated.
                    MessageBox.Show("has been added successfully.");
                }
```

How do I get SQL to retun "q" as 1 / fail / error if the RETURN has kicked in and stopped the procedure so the C# does not take the query as "successful"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to return a value and then catch that value in a parameter added via the code. Here's some example code for you.

sql sp

> ```
>      // SQL sp
>            Begin
>            Return 200    
>            End
> ```

c#

```
// C#
  using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=Northwinds; Integrated Security=true;"))
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand();
                sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcom.CommandText = "myProcedure";
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 254;

                // this can be named anything I just used @r
                SqlParameter returnParameter = sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@r", SqlDbType.Int);
                // specify parameter is a return
                returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                sqlcom.Connection = sqlcon;
                sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // get return value
                int result = (int)sqlcom.Parameters["@r"].Value ;
                sqlcon.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my main problem was I had in ' sqlcom.CommandText = " EXECUTE myProcedure" ' and then left out "sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;" But I have changed it to be the same as yours, and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use RAISERROR to create errors using your own logic. These begin the error processing process and should be processed as a normal error would which should throw it to C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx